# Remove ripple effect from RadioButton, android?

Tags: android

I have custom styled a RadioButton for adding radiobutton image on the right side

```
<RadioButton
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/custom_btn_radio"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Invite Only"/>
```

custom_btn_radio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/close_btn" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

but, the radiobutton's ripple effect also enlarged. how can i remove ripple effect from RadioButton? and also how to customize ripple effect?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just set RadioButton background to transparent.

Comment: Thank you @Harry i set android:background="#ffffffff". is there any other way to set background transparent?

Comment: @android:color/transparent

Comment: Thank you once again @Harry

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Make RadioButton background to transparent

```
android:background="#00ffffff"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: This work for me -> android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: the first one makes it white color with full opacity

Comment: The first one should be #00FFFFFF, as first two numbers are the opacity and FF neams 100% opaque, while 00 means 100% transparent

Comment: First solution must be `#00ffffff` and not `#ffffffff`

Answer (score 3):

Setting `colorControlHighlight` and `colorControlActivated` to transparent color solved this issue for me:

```
<style name="transparent_theme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the "how to customize ripple effect" part, using Material Components library v1.1.0, the background is by default a `RippleDrawable` with its color set to a `ColorStateList` of 2 colors: A 26 alpha (#A1 in hex) `colorControlActivated` in enabled and checked state, and for the default state an alpha white or black depending on whether you have a light (#1F000000) or dark theme (#33FFFFFF). I retrieved this info simply by inspecting the background of a `MaterialCheckBox` in the debugger.

You can just override the color of the `RippleDrawable` however you wish using its `setColor` method. For example, if you want to only change the accent colored part of the ripple effect while using a DayNight theme, you can run this Kotlin code sample:

```
private val RIPPLE_ENABLED_CHECKED_STATES = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_checked),
        intArrayOf())

fun Int.withAlpha(alpha: Int): Int {
    require(alpha in 0..0xFF)
    return this and 0x00FFFFFF or (alpha shl 24)
}

fun CompoundButton.changeCheckedRippleColor(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    val defaultAlphaColor= if (context.resources.configuration.uiMode and 
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            Color.WHITE.withAlpha(51)
        else
            Color.BLACK.withAlpha(31)
    (background as? RippleDrawable)?.setColor(ColorStateList(RIPPLE_ENABLED_CHECKED_STATES,
                intArrayOf(color.withAlpha(26), defaultAlphaColor)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly you should crate a new ripple_checkbox_bg.xml in the drawable folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent"> <!-- ripple color -->

    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/> <!-- for a transparent background. if you want you can use different color -->

</ripple>
```

and put this code your **style.xml**

```
<style name="custom_radio_button_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ripple</item>
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_btn_radio</item>
</style>
```

and

and finally you can put this code your activity xml file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                style="@style/custom_radio_button_style"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Ripple effect removed"
             />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent"> <!-- ripple color -->

    <item android:drawable="your color"/> <!-- normal color -->

</ripple>
```

Comment: how to add this to my RadioButton ?