# Xamarin.Forms Listview does not show selection ripple effect

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project (for Android only at the moment).
I found a lot of questions where people want to remove the ripple effect:
See for example :

- [Xamarin.Forms untappable ListView (remove selection ripple effect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586243/xamarin-forms-untappable-listview-remove-selection-ripple-effect?rq=1)
- [How to get rid of the listview ripple effect in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085732/how-to-get-rid-of-the-listview-ripple-effect-in-xamarin-forms)

But in my case, the ListView Viewcells does **not** show that effect on selection. I've already verified it has no background color. I want that effect when the user taps a Viewcell. The thing is that it works in another project I made, but I can't figure out why it does not here.

My questions:

- Is this effect native in Android (API 25 on the device)
- For what reason(s) could it not be present when touching the cells ?

My Listview XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PickingParts}"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          SeparatorColor="Transparent"
          RowHeight="100"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPickingPart, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <local:PickingPartItemTemplate />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

And the ItemTemplate:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"
             x:Class="MyNamespace.PickingPartItemTemplate">

    <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                 Padding="0"
                 HorizontalOptions="Fill">

        <StackLayout Spacing="5"
                     Padding="0,0,0,0"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">

            <!-- References -->
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         Margin="2,0,2,0">

                <Label TextColor="{DynamicResource BaseTextColor}">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="{Binding Reference}"
                                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                                  ForegroundColor="{DynamicResource DarkTextColor}" />
                            <Span Text=" " />
                            <Span Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Comment}"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       FontSize="14"
                       Opacity=".5"
                       TextColor="{DynamicResource BaseTextColor}" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Quantities -->
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                         HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                         Margin="2,0,2,0"
                         WidthRequest="80">

                <Label TextColor="{DynamicResource BaseTextColor}"
                       FontSize="14"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="End">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="{Binding Qty}"
                                  FontAttributes="Bold"
                                  ForegroundColor="{DynamicResource DarkTextColor}" />
                            <Span Text=" " />
                            <Span Text="{Binding UnitCode}"
                                  FontSize="10" />
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>

                <Label TextColor="{Binding StatusColor}"
                       FontSize="14"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="End">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.ShoppingCart}"
                                  FontFamily="FontAwesome" />
                            <Span Text="  " />
                            <Span Text="{Binding PrepareQty}"
                                  FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Bottom Line -->
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding StatusColor}"
                 HeightRequest="2"
                 VerticalOptions="End" />

    </StackLayout>  
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Had you found any solution?